# Appcelerator message = "JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier \"undefined\"";

Tags: json, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am adding new features to an app I wrote last years and is working now ... I just port the code from Appcelerator (3.2...) to the Appcelerator Studio 5.2.0.GA SDK ... and I have spent 2 days trying to figure out why code that currently works on an app in the app store is not working in the SDK 5.2.0 environment

I keep getting the above error .. I am positive the url is correct and working

This line of code works now in the app in the store and in 3.1... but is not working in 5.2.0

> var jsonObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

It gives the above error 
 "JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier \"undefined\"";

I have read their site and searched for a solution ... Thanks 
entire Block

Comment: Does your "JSON" have `undefined` in it? That's not valid JSON.

Comment: Try using `this.responseData` instead of `this.responseText` : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-responseData. Before doing JSON.parse, try to log the response to see if it's a valid JSON with : `Ti.API.log('this.responseText ' + this.responseText);`

Answer (score 2):

Try one thing:

- Open this site and put your response data in which you are getting error  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com
- After parsing the same data on the above site, you can check whether the problem is really in your Titanium code or in your data.
- Also check whether you are really getting any response data or not.
- If it does not help, then please share some necessary source code

Thanks